# How throws CustomException from reactive service to controller?

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I am receiving a request in a 0.`RestController` and give it to the service for processing. If service doesnt throw `exception`, i just return `HttpStatus.200`, but if an exception occurs in the service, i need catch it in controller and return the status depending on the exception.
Inside service, i need to use `Mono.fromCallable` for repo access. Well, if user not found, i try throw my `CustomException`, but i cant cach it in controller. What am I doing wrong?

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class CardStatusController {

    private final CardStatusService cardStatusService;

    @PostMapping(value = "api/{user_id}/confirm", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
  
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<HttpStatus>> confirmStatus(
            @PathVariable("user_id") String userId,
            @RequestBody CardStatusRequest statusRequest) {
        
        statusRequest.setUserId(userId);
        
        cardStatusService.checkCardStatus(statusRequest);

        return Mono.just(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK));
    }

    @ExceptionHandler({ CheckCardStatusException.class })
    public void handleException() {
        log.error("error!");
    }
```

My service:

```
    public Mono<Void> checkCardStatus(CardStatusRequest statusRequest) throws CheckCardStatusException {
        if (statusRequest.getCardEmissionStatus().equals(CardEmissionStatus.ACCEPTED)) {
            String reference = statusRequest.getReference();
            return Mono.fromCallable(() -> userRepository.findById(statusRequest.getUserId()))
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                    .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new CheckCardStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)))
                    .flatMap(user -> Mono.fromCallable(() -> cardRepository.findFireCardByUserId(user.getId()))
                            .flatMap(optionalCard -> {
                                if (optionalCard.isPresent()) {
                                    if (optionalCard.get().getExtId().isEmpty()) {
                                        Card card = optionalCard.get();
                                        card.setExtId(reference);
                                        try {
                                            cardRepository.save(card);
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            return Mono.error(new CheckCardStatusException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR));
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        if (!optionalCard.get().getExtId().equals(reference)) {
                                                return Mono.error(new CheckCardStatusException(HttpStatus.CONFLICT));
                                            }
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    Card card = new Card();
                                    //set card params
                                    try {
                                        cardRepository.save(card);
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        return Mono.error(new CheckCardStatusException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR));
                                    }
                                }
                                return Mono.error(new CheckCardStatusException(HttpStatus.OK));
                            })).then();
        }
        else {
            return Mono.error(new CheckCardStatusException(HttpStatus.OK));
        }
    }
}
```

My CustomException:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class CheckCardStatusException extends RuntimeException {
    private HttpStatus httpStatus;
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the `Mono` returned by `checkCardStatus` is never subscribed to and as a result the functionality will never be invoked.

Comment: hiren. no, the reason not here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Mono` returned by `checkCardStatus` is never subscribed, so the error signal is ignored. You have to return the whole chain to the Webflux framework as follows:

```
public Mono<ResponseEntity<HttpStatus>> confirmStatus(
        @PathVariable("user_id") String userId,
        @RequestBody CardStatusRequest statusRequest) {
    
    statusRequest.setUserId(userId);
    
    return cardStatusService.checkCardStatus(statusRequest)
            .then(Mono.just(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK)));
}
```

In case of an error, the corresponding `ExceptionHandler` will be executed.

Comment: Thank you, its works. But now, if service doesnt throw some exception, i have NOP in controller, and case Mono.just(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK)) not works. I think its because service returns null. Can you tell me, how can i change my service?

Comment: @Anton  When working in reactive world you should never return `null` from any method. Use `.then()` operator instead of `.flatMap(user -> { return null;})`

Comment: This topic is very difficult for me, because I have just started programming, and I have already got on a project with WebFlux. Thank you very much, you helped me a lot!

Comment: dear, one more question: if I need to work with user further in the chain, then I will have to use flatMap, and I will not be able to apply then(). For example, if I need to change the user's name and save it, how can I write it in this case?

Comment: @Anton You can use as many `flatmap`s as you want before `then`. See https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#then--

Comment: thank you for being very patient))!!
I posted the full code of my service, but I don't like that I have to return something from it anyway. If everything went well in the service and I just want to finish it, I still need to throw an error with HttpStatus.OK, to intercept it in the controller and return it to the front. Please show me how it can be done correctly and beautifully?

Comment: @Anton `I don't like that I have to return something from it anyway` I'm not sure what you mean here. Feel free to open a new question explaining in detail what you are trying to achieve.